# Runtime permission with 2 request in the same activity

Tags: android, permissions, runtime

I'm trying to ask for 2 runtime permissions int he same activity.
The first one will trigger by button and ask for READ_CONTACTS, if allowed will go forward via onActivityResult.
The other runtime permission will ask SEND_SMS and if allowed will go to onRequestPermissionsResult.
Now, as I understand how it workd - I'm doing it wrong.
The 2 runtime permissions need to run through one of this choices and I need to build a method with Switch Case or something to handle the 2 permissions so it won't crash.
I need idea how to handle this 2 events so I won't allow the contacts permission and the activity will try to run the SMS method.

That's the onActivityResult override that I can't get rid of.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
            uriContact = data.getData();

            retrieveContactNumber();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.getStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(SmsActivity.this, "Hi, I Tried :P", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



private void retrieveContactNumber() {

    Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID}, null, null, null);

    if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

        contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    }

    cursorID.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);


    Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

            new String[]{contactID},
            null);

    if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
        contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }

    cursorPhone.close();
    txtCbNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNum);
    txtCbNum.setText(contactNumber, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
}


private void requestSmsPermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SmsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SmsActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                PERMISSION_SEND_SMS);
    } else {
        contactNumber = txtCbNum.getText().toString();
        sendSms(contactNumber, dibur);
    }


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_SEND_SMS) {

        contactNumber = txtCbNum.getText().toString();

        sendSms(contactNumber, dibur);
    } else if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        try {
            // need to insert the contact number retrieve here

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(SmsActivity.this, "Hi, I Tried :P", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(SmsActivity.this, "Permission denied, Can't send SMS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}


private void sendSms(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    try {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(SmsActivity.this, "Sms sent successfully to " + contactNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(SmsActivity.this, "SMS failed, please try again." + contactNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell your two `requestPermissions()` calls apart by the integer that you are passing as the second parameter. That value is supplied to `onRequestPermissionsResult()` as a parameter.

So, for example, if in one place you have:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, ..., RESULT_PERMS_RECORD_VIDEO);
```

(with an array of permission names for `...`)

and in another place you have:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, ..., RESULT_PERMS_TAKE_PICTURE);
```

(with, presumably, a different array of permission names for `...`)

then you can have:

```
  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                         String[] permissions,
                                         int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode==RESULT_PERMS_TAKE_PICTURE) {
      // do something
    }
    else if (requestCode==RESULT_PERMS_RECORD_VIDEO) {
      // do something else
    }
  }
```

Comment: I added the second problem that your offer makes while try to handle the data from the contacts

Comment: @user3181843: I do not understand the nature of your problem. Either request the permissions before picking the contact, or request the permissions after picking the contact but before retrieving the contact number. If you go with the latter approach, hold onto the `Uri` of the picked contact in a field of the activity or fragment that you are in.

Comment: Sorry, I edited again with all the code.
Trying to pull data in the onActivityResult and then in the "retrieveContactNumber" to get only the number from the data